# Alternative application server for Bosun

Tags: fiware-bosun

As far as I understand, fiware-bosun uses Django server. However, is it possible to deploy it using a different application server (e.g. Apache)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiware-bosun is compound by two different modules:

- Fiware-cloto: The Rule engine which uses Django server with WSGI.
- Fiware-facts: the server to process the incoming facts, which uses Flask + Gevent with WSGI.

Both components are recommended to be deployed using gunicorn and you could also add supervisord and Nginx over this layer.

However, of course you can deploy the rule engine using any other application server that supports WSGI (e.g. Apache + mod_wsgi).